# phpMyAdmin - Error session_start

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, centos, vesta

Полный текст ошибки:

Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

При входе в phpmyadmin вылазит такая ошибка, chmod на папку /var/lib/php/session/ ставил, да и tmp папка под рутом стоит и в php.ini раскомментировал и прописал session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"

Ничего не помогает, знает ли кто как с этим бороться?
CentOS 6.9 VestaCP httpd + nginx

Comment: Кто владелец /var/lib/php/session и под каким пользователем выполняется php?

Comment: под root apache но и под root:root тоже не работает

Comment: таже проблема. на какие на все папки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему, когда я установил на весту https://github.com/Skamasle/sk-php-selector php селектор то нужно было на все папки пыхи установить права а не только на текущую которая работает на сервере.